# Ĉu ekzistas gramatika nomo por kunmetaĵoj kiel "hejmeniri"?

Tags: grammar

Mi parolas specife pri kunmetaĵoj kiuj enhavas la akuzativon de movo, *-en*, ekz. *hejm**en**iri*, kiu signifas (kompreneble) *iri hejmen.*

Krome, ĉu tiaj kunmetaĵoj estas ĝustaj? Mi ne trovas la vorton *hejmeniri* en PIV, tamen ja aperis 26 trafoj de "hejmenir" je Tekstaro. Krom tio mi nur povas diri ke mi multfoje aŭdis kaj uzis tiajn kunmetaĵojn.

Answer (score 7):

Ebla nomo estas **kunmetaĵo kun almova adverba flankelemento**.

La elemento estas adverbo, do la finaĵo *-n* ne indikas veran akuzativon.

Sube estas citaĵo el *Plena Analiza Gramatiko*, §309.3, "Konservo de finaĵoj":

> La finaĵo **n**, signanta almovon, regule persistas ĉe adverboj: *antaŭeniri, antaŭenpuŝi; flankeniri, flankenĵetiĝi; hejmenreveno; malsuprenflugo, malsupreniri, malsuprenĵeti* ktp., sed antaŭ *iĝi* kaj *igi* oni trovas ĝin nur en *supreniĝi* (ascendi), *malsupreniĝi* (descendi) kaj *antaŭeniĝi* (avanci); cetere oni uzas prepoziciajn prefiksoidojn: *deflankiĝi*<sup>Z</sup> (ne: flankeniĝi!), *alfundiĝi* (ne: fundeniĝi!). Tiel same oni procedas ĉe finaĵa pluformado: *alsupra* (ne: suprena!). Ĉe prepozicioj oni ĉiam ellasas la finaĵon **n**: *suriri, subiri, eniri,* kelkfoje eĉ ĉe substantiva flankelemento: *ĉieliro*.

Tiaj reguloj estas iomete pedantaj. Mi konjektas, ke ili malpermesas *flankeniĝi* pro ke oni povus tro facile miskompreni ĝin kiel *flank-eniĝi*, ktp.

Comment: Dankon por tiu klariga citaĵo. Do, laŭ via konjekto, "flankeniĝi", "fundeniĝi" ktp. ja uzeblas, tamen oni ĝenerale evitas ilin por eviti malklarecon, ĉu ne? Do laŭ kunteksto (teorie), oni ja povus diri "fundeniĝi" kaj estus komprenebla--tamen laŭ kutima uzo, tio ne ofte okazas. Ĉu mi bone komprenis? Ĉiuokaze, dankon por trovi la informon.

Comment: Kaj pri tiu ebla nomo, ĝi ŝajnas sufiĉe klara. Eble ĉi aldonitan *-n* oni ankaŭ povus nomigi "almova adverba infikso". Ĉu tio estas facile komprenebla? Espereble mi ne miskomprenas la signifon de *infikso*.

Comment: Konsideru la citaĵon kiel konsilo de unu gramatikisto. Ĝenerale, en teksto oni povas enmeti streketon por unusignifigi kunmetaĵon. Koncerne vian duan komenton, la vorton *infikso* oni uzas pri aldono interna de radiko. La *-n* adheras al *hejme* kiel sufikso interna nur de kunmetaĵo. Do, eble tio kion vi serĉas estas *kunmetaĵo kun interna almova sufikso*.